# Saving a recursive object in Datastore via Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, datastore

I have a use case where in I have to save a recursive object

Two classes :

```
public class Item{

@Id
private Long id;

@Index
private String name;

@Index
private String sku;

@Index
private Long shopId;
@Index
private String imageUrl="";

@Index
private List<Long>optionIds;

private List<Option> options;
}

public class Option{

@Id
private Long id;

@Index
private String name;

@Index
private String sku;

@Index
private Long shopId;
@Index
private String imageUrl="";

@Index
private List<Long>itemIds;

private List<Item> items;
}
```

I do save the two objects separately in two different tables as well.
For that I need to add @Ignore on the List field in the Item model
and @Ignore on the List field in the Option model.

I now need a complete recursive structure and want to save that in another table. 
To do that I was trying a hack by putting @IgnoreSave(IfNull.class) on the List field in the Item model and on the List field in the Option model.

But when I launched the application after doing the above, I got a stackoverflow error. Error being something of the below sort :

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.getMemberMethods(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:284)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.equalsImpl(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:196)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:63)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.equals(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.equals(Arrays.java:1869)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.TypeKey.equals(TypeKey.java:60)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:996)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.Translators.get(Translators.java:115)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext.getTranslator(CreateContext.java:27)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.KeyMetadata.findKeyFields(KeyMetadata.java:78)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.KeyMetadata.<init>(KeyMetadata.java:50)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslatorFactory.createEntityClassTranslator(ClassTranslatorFactory.java:64)
```

I'm stuck now and need help badly. Is there an alternative solution to store the recursive structure via objectify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to save two different entities that reference each other. For that, you should use `Key<?>` or `Ref<?>` fields. Recursion is no problem with pointers like this.

By specifying `List<Item>` and `List<Option>`, you are telling Objectify that you want to *embed* these things recursively in a single entity. Objectify does not support recursive embedded classes (at least, not yet).